# opencv python error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting an error while running the following code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('messi.jpg',0)
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(50,50),(255,0,0),5)
cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error says:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "F:\Computer programming\scripts\OpenCv\1.py", line 6, in 
>       cv2.imshow("image",img)
>   cv2.error: ......\src\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0

If I remove the line:

```
img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(50,50),(255,0,0),5)
```

the script works.

Comment: The message says your img is empty. Your file 'messi.jpg' is not in your working directory. You likely need to specify a proper path to it.

Answer (score 4):

Its because `cv2.line` returns `None` and you are assigning that to your `img` variable. So when you get to the next line and try to show the image, there is no image to be shown.

Replace `img = cv2.line(img,(0,0),(50,50),(255,0,0),5)` with `cv2.line(img,(0,0),(50,50),(255,0,0),5)`

[Read more about cv2.circle here.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html)

Comment: The tutorial should be corrected [Opencv drawing options](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html)