# OpenCV(4.2.0) error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, argparse, opencv, imshow

I've been getting this error. I have copied the code from [This website](https://data-flair.training/blogs/project-in-python-colour-detection/) and making changes so that the code actually works. The code:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']

#Reading image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

#Reading csv file with pandas and giving names to each column
index=["color","color_name","hex","R","G","B"]

csv = pd.read_csv('colors.csv', names=index, header=None)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_function)

while(1): 
    #This is error line
    cv2.imshow("image",img)
    [...]
```

The full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\someone\Documents\python\____The Useless Installer____\PY\color_detection.py", line 39, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722467/opencv-python-error-assertion-failed-size-width0-size-height0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739788/how-to-solve-cv2-error-215-size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imsho) but I don't understand how to fix this and I don't think it relates to my question that much either. If this is obvious I am very sorry. I'm a complete newbie at this. Thanks

Comment: How are you launching the script? Are you passing the `--image` argument() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this error tells you that you are trying to show an **empty** / **non existent** image. Please do check:

- *The path*: I think the problem comes from `cv2.imread()`. *If the path is incorrect, the `img` variable will be empty*.

***The way you tried*** to read the image is almost right:

`img = cv2.imread(C:\Users\someone\Documents\python\____The Useless Installer____\PY\colorpic)`

***The way it should be***:

- double backslash for escaping the `"\"` character which has a special meaning in programming languages
- you do need to enter the format of the picture (`jpeg`, `png`, etc..).
- you need to pass this argument as a `'string'` or `"string"`

---

**Therefore try** `img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\someone\\Documents\\python\\____The Useless Installer____\\PY\\colorpic.jpg")`

---